# Delete column if items don't contain a Number

Tags: python, list, matrix

Really stuck here and need some advice please....

I have a list ...

```
transposedlist = [('-', '*', '*', '1'), ('7', '6', '6', '1'), ('-', '*', '1', '*'), ('-', '*', '*', '*'), ('1', '3', '3', '*'), ('-', ' ', ' ', '*'),
```

each group in the transposedlist above represents a column in a Matrix.

I would like to delete any group which contains NO numbers.

Heres my attempt thus far...

```
for i, group in enumerate(Listoflists):
    if "-" in group[1:] == group[:-1] or "*" in group[1:] == group[:-1] or group[1:] None == group[:1]:
        Matrix.DeleteColumn(i)
```

The code above checks of the 1st item is the same as the last item in the group, if it is then it should delete the column, this is not ideal obviously because it ignores the items in the middle.

Any suggestions?

Comment: By saying you want to delete columns you're adding additional confusion to the question. What you actually want is to delete *rows* from `transposedlist`. It's not relevant to the question that it represent a matrix that is a transposition of a original one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`any()` function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) with a list comprehension to *keep* entries with numbers instead:

```
transposedlist = [entry for entry in transposedlist if any(e.isdigit() for e in entry)]
```

The `any()` function here returns `True` if there is any value in the iterable (a generator expression here) that is `True`, `False` otherwise. If the expression `(e.isdigit() for e in entry)` only yields `False` then that `entry` will not be included in the new list.

Demo:

```
>>> transposedlist = [('-', '*', '*', '1'), ('7', '6', '6', '1'), ('-', '*', '1', '*'), ('-', '*', '*', '*'), ('1', '3', '3', '*'), ('-', ' ', ' ', '*')]
>>> any(e.isdigit() for e in transposedlist[0])
True
>>> any(e.isdigit() for e in transposedlist[3])
False
>>> [entry for entry in transposedlist if any(e.isdigit() for e in entry)]
[('-', '*', '*', '1'), ('7', '6', '6', '1'), ('-', '*', '1', '*'), ('1', '3', '3', '*')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a [list-comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> transposedlist = [('-', '*', '*', '1'), ('7', '6', '6', '1'), ('-', '*', '1', '*'), ('-', '*', '*', '*'), ('1', '3', '3', '*'), ('-', ' ', ' ', '*')]
>>> newlist = [x for x in transposedlist if any(y.isdigit() for y in x)]   
>>> newlist
[('-', '*', '*', '1'), ('7', '6', '6', '1'), ('-', '*', '1', '*'), ('1', '3', '3', '*')]
>>>
```

If you want to read more, here are references on [`any`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#any) and [`str.isdigit`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit)

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
import string

transposedlist = [('-', '*', '*', '1'), ('7', '6', '6', '1'), ('-', '*', '1', '*'), ('-', '*', '*', '*'), ('1', '3', '3', '*'), ('-', ' ', ' ', '*')]

newlist = [x for x in transposedlist if re.search("[0-9]",string.join(x,"")) is not None]
```